# What does 'grep -v "^[...]"' mean?

Tags: grep, diff

I wrote a line like this `diff fileA.txt fileB.txt | grep -v "^[11,12d9]"` .
Without the `grep` part, the output would look like this:

```
1d0  
< loop  
11,12d9  
< polo  
< pool
```

But with `grep`, the output would look like this:

```
< loop  
< polo  
< pool
```

I think that `grep -v` is kind of like reverse search. But I don't understand the `^[11,12d9]` part, what does it do?

Comment: What inspired you to write that particular line? What did you actually want to achieve?

Comment: `-v` is not reverse search (it does not read the file/stream backwards). It is a inverted filter (find those that don't match).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`grep -v "^[11,12d9]"`

yes, as you found out `-v` is used for invert match and will return lines that do not match the given *pattern* `^[11,12d9]`.

and what `^[11,12d9]` is doing is that saying match characters in `[...]` and if they were appeared at the begging of a line (`^` is the beginning of the line anchor) then ignore those lines (since of used `-v` invert match);

so basically lines that started with one of `1`, `,`, `2`, `d` or`9` characters will be ignored (repeated characters also will be ignored within character-class).

but if you would like to ignore the line starting with string `11,12d9`, you need `grep -v '^11,12d9'`.

---

*Not relevant to the question but to keep notes about use of `]`, `^` and `-` characters within character class:

if `^` character: it can be placed anywhere in `[]` but not the first character; if it was first character, it acts as negation on the characters within that class.
if `]` character: it should be the first character.
if `-` character: it should be the last character.